# Does anyone know how to use AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1 on delphi?

Tags: delphi, tms

Does anyone know how to use AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1 ?
Because i want to customize this before execute like label Align and Edit text Align
i used like like code below

```
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues.Clear;
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues.Add;
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues[0].&Name:='Name';
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues[0].&Label:='User Name:';
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues[0].&EditType  :=etString ;
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues[0].&EditAlign :=eaCenter;

 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues.Clear;
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues.Add;
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues[1].&Name:='Name';
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues[1].&Label:='User Name:';
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues[1].&EditType  :=etPassword
 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.QueryValues[1].&EditAlign :=eaCenter;

 AdvMultiInputQueryDialog1.Execute();
```

but it get error like this !

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(38): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'etString'
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(39): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'eaCenter'
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(45): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'etPassword'
```

Comment: The documentation tells you what is wrong and how to fix it http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/E2003_Undeclared_identifier_%27%25s%27_(Delphi)

Comment: On a side note, you don't need to prefix member names with `&` unless they are using reserved keywords, which `Name`, `EditType` and `EditAlign` do not, but `Label` does

Answer (score 0):

The error means you have not included the required unit in your uses clause.

Use a search program like `Agent Ransack` to search through the source files to find the declaration of `etPassword` etc.. and then add that file to your uses clause.

Comment: No need for any tools. Can search files directly in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It's a missing unit problem, try adding `advedit` to uses section.